# Incomplete type is not allowed but I cannot find the reason why. Pls help me <3

Tags: c

So for the time being im trying to insert a struct into a linked list and for some reason when i try to push a new struct aka make a new node, i have this error on void push and i have no clue why. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have wasted couple of hours into this. Thank you for your time! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>





typedef struct Rect Rect;
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef enum {red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black} Color;


struct Rect{
    int id, x, y, w, h, area, filled;
    Color colour;
};

struct node_t{
    Rect obj;
    node_t *next;
};

void push(const node_t *p, node_t **head_ptr)
{
    node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));//the problem is here: It underlines with red the "sizeof" and says incomplete type is not allowed
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->rect = *p;
    new_node->next = *head_ptr;
    *head_ptr = new_node;


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a real close look at these lines:

```
typedef struct node node_t;  // what is the typedef name, and what is the tag?
...
struct node_t{               // what is the tag name?
    Rect obj;
    node_t *next;
};
```

Short answer is, you never define a `struct node` type for the `node_t` typedef.  You need to change your struct definition from `struct node_t {` to `struct node {`.

Comment: Or change the typedef

Comment: @Barmar: Or that, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much, im dum, i didn't see that at all!. How can I mark this as answered? Or delete it?

Comment: @Δημητρης Μπαμπας: There should be a grayed-out check mark next to my answer, just click on that to mark it as accepted.